# Javascript/jQuery group and sort group

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, sorting

I currently have a series of divs that are generated by our MVC app.
I am attempting to sort by a variety of 'data-' attributes.
I was able to group the items by an attribute called 'data-categoryname'.

Each item also has a 'data-categorysortorder' in which I want to sort the group that gets created by the 'data-categoryname' by that sort order value.

I have a JS Fiddle started, and have the groupings grouped, I now need help sorting the groups by category name by the 'category sort order'.  Any help is appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/c0fawcnf/9/

```
//CURRENTLY HAVE GROUPING BY CATEGORY ITEM NAME AND WRAPPING EACH GROUP BY CATEGORY NAME, BUT NOW NEED TO SORT EACH CATEGORY WRAPPER BY THE ITEMS 'data-categorydisplayorder'

var $item = $('.item-box'),
   items = {};

$item.each(function () {
    items[$(this).data('categoryitemname')] = '';
});

for (category in items) {
    var categoryLowerCase = category.toLowerCase();
     $item.filter('[data-categoryitemname=' + category + ']').wrapAll('<div id="' + categoryLowerCase + '" class="categoryWrapper" data-wrappercategorydisplayorder="NEED_CATEGORY_DISPLAY_VALUE_HERE_AND_SORT_BY_THIS_VALUE"></div>');
    //return list;
    $('div#' + categoryLowerCase + '').prepend('<div class="page-title"><h1>' + category.replace("-", " ") + '</h1></div>');
}


// THESE ITEMS ARE OUTPUTTED BY AN MVC APPLICATION TO THE UI - I NEED TO SORT ON THE CLIENT SIDE BASED ON PARAMETERS

<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Fall" data-itemsortorder="2" data-categorydisplayorder="2">Fall Item</div>
<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Fall" data-itemsortorder="0"  data-categorydisplayorder="2">Fall Item</div>
<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Fall" data-itemsortorder="1"  data-categorydisplayorder="2">Fall Item</div>

<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Summer" data-itemsortorder="2"  data-categorydisplayorder="1">Summer Item</div>
<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Summer" data-itemsortorder="1"  data-categorydisplayorder="1">Summer Item</div>
<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Summer" data-itemsortorder="0"  data-categorydisplayorder="1">Summer Item</div>

<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Winter" data-itemsortorder="2"  data-categorydisplayorder="3">Winter Item</div>
<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Winter" data-itemsortorder="1"  data-categorydisplayorder="3">Winter Item</div>
<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Winter" data-itemsortorder="0"  data-categorydisplayorder="3">Winter Item</div>

<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Spring" data-itemsortorder="1"  data-categorydisplayorder="0">Spring Item</div>
<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Spring" data-itemsortorder="2"  data-categorydisplayorder="0">Spring Item</div>
<div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Spring" data-itemsortorder="0"  data-categorydisplayorder="0">Spring Item</div>
```

I did a lot of searching on how to sort items, but found many that sorted elements in known element with an ID that exists on the page already.   Since I am dynamically adding the groups to the DOM then sorting after the creation of the groups, I have not really found anything on how to do that.

**UPDATE:**
I got the sort order value to attach to the group element. but the sort function I have is still not working.  I updated my JS Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/c0fawcnf/12/

```
// CURRENTLY HAVE GROUPING BY CATEGORY ITEM NAME AND WRAPPING EACH GROUP BY CATEGORY NAME, BUT NOW NEED TO SORT EACH CATEGORY WRAPPER BY THE ITEMS 'data-categorydisplayorder'

var $item = $('.item-box'),
   items = {};

$item.each(function () {
    items[$(this).data('categoryitemname')] = '';
});

for (category in items) {
    var categoryLowerCase = category.toLowerCase();
     $item.filter('[data-categoryitemname=' + category + ']').wrapAll('<div id="' + categoryLowerCase + '" class="categoryWrapper" data-wrappercategorydisplayorder="NEED_CATEGORY_DISPLAY_VALUE_HERE_AND_SORT_BY_THIS_VALUE"></div>');
    //return list;
    $('div#' + categoryLowerCase + '').prepend('<div class="page-title"><h1>' + category.replace("-", " ") + '</h1></div>');

    // GET ITEM BOX DISPLAY ORDER PROPERTY AND ATTACH IT TO THE WRAPPER CATEGORY DISPLAY PROPERTY
    var elem = $('div#' + categoryLowerCase + ' .item-box');
    elem.parent().attr("data-wrappercategorydisplayorder", elem.data("categorydisplayorder"));
}


// ATTEMPT TO SORT - BUT NOT WORKING
$('.productCategoryWrapper').sort(sort_items).appendTo('#item-grid');

//IS THIS EVEN CORRECT?
 function sort_items(a, b) {
     console.log('we shall sort');
     return ($(b).data('wrappercategorydisplayorder')) < ($(a).data('wrappercategorydisplayorder')) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting to sort the groups by `categorydisplayorder` (so the output will be Spring-Summer-Fall-Winter) and also sort the items within each group by `itemsortorder` (the items within a group all have the same text so that bit is confusing)

Comment: Right now I am just wanting to sort the groups by 'categorydisplayorder' (so the output will be Spring-Summer-Fall-Winter).

Comment: OK - I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0fawcnf/10/) to do the sorting on items within one of the groups (before I understood exactly what you were wanting to do). In your case, you will need a container around the groups and when you create the container for each group, add a `data-sortorder` attribute so you can use it in a similar way. I'm about to take a break, but if you have not worked it out, I'll add an answer in an hour or so

Comment: @StephenMuecke.  That is not exactly what I wanted, but sorting within the groups may be helpful in the future, but right now I need to update or sort the groups.  I added an Update with an update to my Fiddle in my question where I was able to add the sort order to the group element from the children. But now I need to sort the group.  So I have a function attempting to do that at this point.  I will see if any of your sort code could help me with the group sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED IT**

The way I needed it to. In case anyone else is interested. Here is the solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/c0fawcnf/14/

**HTML**

```
  <!--THESE ITEMS ARE OUTPUTTED BY AN MVC APPLICATION TO THE UI - I NEED TO SORT ON THE CLIENT SIDE BASED ON PARAMETERS-->
<div id="item-grid">


   <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Fall" data-itemsortorder="2" data-categorydisplayorder="2">Fall Item</div>
   <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Fall" data-itemsortorder="0"  data-categorydisplayorder="2">Fall Item</div>
    <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Fall" data-itemsortorder="1"  data-categorydisplayorder="2">Fall Item</div>

  <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Summer" data-itemsortorder="2"  data-categorydisplayorder="1">Summer Item</div>
   <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Summer" data-itemsortorder="1"  data-categorydisplayorder="1">Summer Item</div>
    <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Summer" data-itemsortorder="0"  data-categorydisplayorder="1">Summer Item</div>

  <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Winter" data-itemsortorder="2"  data-categorydisplayorder="3">Winter Item</div>
   <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Winter" data-itemsortorder="1"  data-categorydisplayorder="3">Winter Item</div>
    <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Winter" data-itemsortorder="0"  data-categorydisplayorder="3">Winter Item</div>

  <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Spring" data-itemsortorder="1"  data-categorydisplayorder="0">Spring Item</div>
   <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Spring" data-itemsortorder="2"  data-categorydisplayorder="0">Spring Item</div>
    <div class="item-box" data-categoryitemname="Spring" data-itemsortorder="0"  data-categorydisplayorder="0">Spring Item</div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
//CURRENTLY HAVE GROUPING BY CATEGORY ITEM NAME AND WRAPPING EACH GROUP BY CATEGORY NAME, BUT NOW NEED TO SORT EACH CATEGORY WRAPPER BY THE ITEMS 'data-categorydisplayorder'

    var $item = $('.item-box'),
       items = {};

    $item.each(function () {
        items[$(this).data('categoryitemname')] = '';
    });

    for (category in items) {
        var categoryLowerCase = category.toLowerCase();
         $item.filter('[data-categoryitemname=' + category + ']').wrapAll('<div id="' + categoryLowerCase + '" class="categoryWrapper" data-wrappercategorydisplayorder=""></div>');
        //return list;
        $('div#' + categoryLowerCase + '').prepend('<div class="page-title"><h1>' + category.replace("-", " ") + '</h1></div>');

   //GET ITEM BOX DISPLAY ORDER PROPERTY AND ATTACH IT TO THE WRAPPER CATEGORY DISPLAY PROPERTY
 var elem = $('div#' + categoryLowerCase + ' .item-box');
//Give the parent element the category display value that is on the child item.
 elem.parent().attr("data-wrappercategorydisplayorder", elem.data("categorydisplayorder"));

    }

  //SORT 
function sort_items(a, b) {
    console.log('we shall sort');
    var a1 = $(a).data('wrappercategorydisplayorder');
    var b1 = $(b).data('wrappercategorydisplayorder');
    return a1 < b1 ? -1 : 1;
}

var ff = $('.categoryWrapper').get().sort(sort_items);

$.each(ff, function(index, item){
    $(this).appendTo('#item-grid');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you will ultimately want to sort the items in each group by the `data-itemsortorder` value, then start by creating a function to sort all the items first by `categorydisplayorder` then by `itemsortorder`

```
function sort_items(a, b) {
    var ai = $(a).data('categorydisplayorder');
    var bi = $(b).data('categorydisplayorder');
    if (ai < bi) {
        return -1;
    } else if (ai > bi) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        ai = $(a).data('itemsortorder');
        bi = $(b).data('itemsortorder');
        if (ai < bi) {
            return -1;
        } else if (ai > bi) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and create a container element to insert the groups

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Then the script to arrange the grouped and sorted items is

```
var groups = [];
var groupcontainer;
var items = $('.item-box');
var sorted = items.get().sort(sort_items); 
$.each(sorted, function (index, item) {
    var group = $(item).data('categoryitemname');
    if (groups.indexOf(group) == -1) {
        groups.push(group);
        var title = $('<div></div>').addClass('page-title').html($('<h1></h1>').text(group));
        groupcontainer = $('<div></div>').addClass('categoryWrapper');
        groupcontainer.append(title);
        $('#container').append(container);
    }
    container.append(item);
});
```

Refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0fawcnf/15/)